# Creating PeriodicTask in celery django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery-beat

I need to send notifications with certain interval when Ticket model instance has been created. For that I decided to use celery-beat.

I created signals.py where I create PeriodicTask intance. When I create new Ticket instance the PeriodicTask instance is created in DB but the task is not running. What do I do wrong?

**signals.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Ticket
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule
import json

@receiver(post_save,sender=Ticket)
def notification_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        interval, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(every=10, period='seconds')
        task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=interval,enabled=True, name='notification_' + str(instance.id), task="create", args=json.dumps((instance.id, )))
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task(name="create")
def create(data):
    print("Some logic here")
```

**celery.py**

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'helpdesk.settings')

app = Celery('helpdesk')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**setting.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
```

The commands I use for launching celery and celery-beat:

**beat**:

celery -A helpdesk beat

**celery**:

celery -A helpdesk worker -l INFO --pool=solo

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the answer. It's needed to launch celery-beat with that command:

celery -A <your_project_name> beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler